# Android - propagating click from parent to child

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a `LinearLayout` with a couple of `TextView`s stacked vertically. I want to attach a click listener to the parent and make the click event propagate to one of the `TextView`s (child views of the containing `LinearLayout`).

I understand that I can attach click listener's to the individual `TextView`s and achieve the same result but I'd like to do otherwise.

I came across the

```
 android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

attribute, but this doesn't seem to solve the issue either. What should I be doing to get the child views to consume the containing parent's click event. Also each text view should perform a different action.

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text_1"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="Text_2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    TextView mTextView1;
    TextView mTextView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
        mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Log.v("view",view.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The log always prints the parent view:

```
    V/view: android.widget.LinearLayout{3ea32ab0 V.E...C. ...PH... 0,0-1080,1533 #7f0c0050 app:id/linear_layout}
    V/view: android.widget.LinearLayout{3ea32ab0 V.E...C. ...PH... 0,0-1080,1533 #7f0c0050 app:id/linear_layout}
```

I am obviously missing something here and hopefully the solution doesn't involve navigating down the view stack. What am I doing wrong, any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: To which one would you want to propagate the click? How would the app know?

Comment: To the TextView that is 'clicked'. That is exactly the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: why you do not want to set onClick Listener to the individual TextViews?

Comment: sorry. @TimCastelijns, I deleted my comment

Answer (score 0):

You may use `setOnTouchListener` for your `LinearLayout`. Inside this `OnTouchListener` you need to detect a click (`GestureDetector` can help) in this point you will have `MotionEvent`, you can get x,y coordinates from this event and compare them with your `TextView`s coordinates. So you can detect which `TextView` was clicked. 
In such a way you can do what you want, but it is complicated, and I believe you can avoid it.

Comment: + for he should avoid it